# Access test case property from test suite tear down script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to access the test case property from test suite tear down script.

i am not able to use test runner properties.

```
def testSuiteProperty = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "MyProp" )
```

Need to access the test case property using test case name.

It will be very helpful if some one can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the test Suite property, it is simply a case of this in your tear down script....

```
def someProp = context.expand( '${#TestSuite#someProp}' )
```

Now, I use the Pro version and I don't know what you're using, so I'm not sure if the next part of my answer will help.

In Setup Script, Tear Down script, Script assertions, you can 'right-click' in the code window where you type your script and there is a 'Get Data' menu item int he context menu.  This allows you to select a piece of data of interest.  In fact, the line of code above was generate by using the 'Get Data' context menu option.

To access a custom property for a given test case within your suite tear-down script, you need to do this...

```
def testCase = testSuite.testCaseList.find { p -> p.name == 'TestCase 2' }
def testProp = testCase.getProperty('testCaseProp');
log.info(testProp.value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris.  I have got answer in the below forum as well .. updating the link below so it may help some one... https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Get-testcase-name-and-testsuite-name-via-property-expansion/td-p/41760

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is not correct

Try using this

```
def testCs =  testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["name of testsuite"].getTestCaseByName(name)
 def tcprop = testCs.getPropertyValue("NameOftestCaseProp")
```

We are first getting refernce of the test case and then accessing its property

or below should also work

```
def testcaseProp= testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["name of testsuite"].getTestCaseByName(name).getPropertyValue("name of property)
```

try whichever looks simple to you, though both are same

Comment: You can do it.  See my example below.  Agreed, the vars aren't in scope and it's not as clean as "def someProp = context.expand( '${#TestSuite#someProp}' )", but my example works.  So, yes, you can access test-level custom properties from the test suite set-up or tear-down scripts.

Comment: You are right, Actually the syntax used by the person is wrong. If we can get the testcase name we can get its property.. will edit my answer